# Let $G$ be a group and $a \in G$. Show that $A=\{x \in G: ax=xa\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> Let $G$ be a group and $a \in G$. Show that $A=\{x \in G: ax=xa\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

My attempt is the following.

Closure follows since
$$
axy=xya \Rightarrow (ax)y=x(ya) \Rightarrow ax, ya \in G
$$
We label them $b':=ax$ and $b'':=ya$.
Following that $b'b=xb''$ holds by proposition, so $xy$ is an element of $A$.

Inverses are contained since
$$
ax=xa \Rightarrow ax^{-1}=x^{-1}a \Rightarrow xa=ax
$$

Associativity and identity follow trivially.

Any tips would be helpful. I'm skeptical on whether I got the closure part right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of them are correct. For closure, you want to show that if $x,y\in A$, then $xy\in A$, and you've done the opposite, I believe, although it's hard to tell. For inverses, you didn't show the intermediate steps, only asserted that the conclusion was true.

Closure follows because $axy=xay=xya$, due to the fact that $a$ commutes with $x$ and $y$.

Inverses follow because multiplication on both the left and right of both sides of the equality $ax=xa$ yields $x^{-1}a=x^{-1}axx^{-1}=x^{-1}xax^{-1}=ax^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

It is useful to use the following easily proved criterion for a subgroup:

> If $H$ is a non-empty subset of a group $G$, and for every $a,b\in H$ also $ab^{-1}\in H$, then $H$ is a subgroup.

The set $A$ is known as the centralizer of $a$ and usually is denoted by $C_G(a)$.
If $x,y\in C_G(a)$ then $xa=ax$ and $ya=ay$, so $xy^{-1}(ay)=xy^{-1}(ya)=xa=ax$,
hence, multiplying both sides by $y^{-1}$, we get $xy^{-1}a=axy^{-1}$ and we are done.

Comment: If $H$ is a *non-empty* subset of a group $G$, and …

Comment: Thank you, @Christoph

Comment: I have to say that personally I have never found that single test method very useful, and in practice it is generally easier to prove closure and the existence of inverses separately.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, in both of your answers you used the hypothesis you were trying to prove. See if the following makes sense.

We have to check $3$ things: Closure, inverses and the identity.

The identity is trivial, it follows from the definition.

Now let's check closure: if $x, y \in A$, then $ax = xa$ and $ay = ya$. Therefore, we have $a(xy) = (ax)y = (xa)y = x(ay) = x(ya) = (xy)a$, so $xy \in A$.

Finally, for inverses, since $ax = xa$, we have that $x^{-1}(ax) = x^{-1}(xa) = ea = a$, which implies $x^{-1}(ax)x^{-1} = ax^{-1} \implies (x^{-1}a)(xx^{-1}) = ax^{-1} \implies x^{-1}a = ax^{-1}$, and so $x^{-1} \in A$.

$A$ is also known as the "centralizer" of "$a$" in the group "$G$" - the notation I've seen before is $C_G(a)$ - in case you want to look-up more about it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need no argument to state that $ax\in G$ and $ya\in G$, because $a$, $x$ and $y$ are elements of $G$.

And you want to show that

> - $1\in A$;
> - if $x\in A$, then $x^{-1}\in A$;
> - if $x,y\in A$, then $xy\in A$.

Starting from $xy\in A$ is the wrongest thing to do: you can easily conclude that $xy\in A$ if you assume it, but it proves nothing regarding your problem.

Others have already given suggestions on how to fix the proof. Here's a proof from a different point of view.

The condition $ax=xa$ can be rewritten as $axa^{-1}=x$, so $A=\{x\in G:axa^{-1}=x\}$.

The map $\varphi_a\colon G\to G$, $\varphi_a(x)=axa^{-1}$ is a group homomorphism (an automorphism actually), because
$$
\varphi_a(x)\varphi_a(y)=axa^{-1}aya^{-1}=a(xy)a^{-1}=\varphi_a(xy)
$$
In general, if $f\colon G\to G$ is a group homomorphism, then the set
$$
F=\{x\in G:f(x)=x\}
$$
is a subgroup of $G$.

- $1\in F$, because $f(1)=1$;
- if $x\in F$, then $f(x^{-1})=f(x)^{-1}=x^{-1}$, therefore $x^{-1}\in F$;
- if $x,y\in F$, then $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)=xy$, therefore $xy\in F$.

In the case of $f=\varphi_a$, we have
$$
F=\{x\in G:\varphi_a(x)=x\}=\{x\in G:axa^{-1}=x\}=A
$$
Hence $A$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

To show closure we have to take two elements from $H_{a}$  i.e. $x$, $y$ $\in Ha$. Then $$(xy)a = x(ya)$$
$$ = xay $$
$$ = (xa)y $$
$$ = axy $$

So H is closed under the operation.

For identity, let $e \in G$ then, for any element $g \in G$, $g*e = e*g = g$
so  $\exists e \in G$
$$x*e=e*x$$
$$x =x$$
So identity is in $H_a$ i.e. $e_{G} \in H_{a}$

if $x \in G $ then $x^{-1} \in G$. Then,
$$ x^{-1} a = a x^{-1}$$
$$  a = xa x^{-1}$$
$$  ax = xa $$
Hence, for every element in $H_a$ inverse is also in $H_a$. $H_a$ is subgroup of $G$.